# Type '(CSSProperties | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have very simple tsx component like this

```
import React, { CSSProperties } from "react";

const INPUT: CSSProperties = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row",
};
const TEXT_INPUT: CSSProperties = {
  fontWeight: "bold",
  marginRight: "10px",
};
const CONTAINER: CSSProperties = {
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  display: "flex",
};
export interface AddNoteInterface {
  style?: CSSProperties;
}
export default function AddNote(props: AddNoteInterface) {
  const { style } = props;
  return (
    <div style={[CONTAINER, style]}>.  <----- ts complaint here
      <div style={INPUT}>
        <div style={TEXT_INPUT}>Text input</div>
        <input />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but when i use array for multi style, it give me error :

```
Type 'CSSProperties[]' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Types of property 'filter' are incompatible.
```

What happen??? Please help, thank you a lots

Comment: I think you mean to merge the two objects, `{...CONTAINER, ...style}`?

Comment: No, i only can use array `[CONTAINER,style]` , if i use `{CONTAINER, style}` it give me error

Comment: I edited the comment. I had missed the spread (`...`) initially

Comment: No it can't, it said `JSX spread child must be an array type.ts(2609)
Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects`

Comment: Please help, i really don't know what to do next

Comment: @CODEforDREAM I tried it in a sandbox with the object spread change maazadeeb suggested `<div style={{ ...CONTAINER, ...style }}>`, and it seems to work just fine. Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-bn22i?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Ah, i misunderstanding @maazadeeb ideal, i wrote `{CONTAINER, style}` instead of `{{ ...CONTAINER, ...style }}`, but why i can't use array? In react native, i can use array for ` viewstyle` and `textStyle`

Comment: @CODEforDREAM well i dunno about those react native properties, but for the `style` property that refers to a bunch of CSS properties, i.e. key/value pairs - so it makes sense that it's an object, cos that's what objects are. When combining objects together you spread them into each other so they form one single object, rather than just sticking a bunch of individual objects into an array.

Comment: @CODEforDREAM and also from Typescript perspective, an object is not the same as an array full of objects. They're different types. So if it's wanting a single object, you can't just pass in an array of objects, it will give that warning since you've given the wrong data type